# Placing circle along a straight line using offset-path

Tags: css, svg

I'm having an issue with moving a circle shape along a dotted line, from right to left.

For some reason, when I use the `d` value of a path as a value for `offset-path` CSS property, the dot appears in a really unexpected position. Attempting to "move" the dot using the `offset-distance` moves the dot off the canvas. What is it that I am missing here?

Here's the code that I am having an issue with:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Moving dot</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100 height=100>
      <path d="M90,50 L10,50" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" stroke="red"></path>
      <circle cx="90" cy="50" r="4"></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I see when rendering the page:

[image]

If I update the `<cirlce>` to include the `style` property, something goes terribly wrong - the dot is now at what appears to be the `0,0` point:

```html
<circle cx="90" cy="50" r="4" style="offset-path: path('M90,50 L10,50');"></circle>
```

Result:

[image]

I was under impression that `offset-path` accepts the `path(...)` containing the same definition of path as the `d` attribute of the SVG `path`. Is that a reason that doesn't appear to be the case?

Comment: You are right - Sorry, I gave you a bad response due to my misunderstanding. I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `offset-path` will add current x/y coordinates

While aligning an element to an offset-path **the element's position is treated as an offset**.
In other words: place your aligned element around the coordinate origin x/y=0.

```css
body{
  margin:2em;
}

svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible
}

#circle{
  offset-path: path('M90,50 L10,50');
  offset-distance: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100 height=100>
  <path d="M90,50 L10,50" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="circle0" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100 height=100>
  <path d="M90,50 L10,50" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100 height=100>
  <path id="mPath" d="M90,50 L10,50" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="0" cy="0" r="4">
    <animateMotion 
                   repeatCount="indefinite" 
                   rotate="auto" 
                   dur="3s" 
                   fill="freeze"
                   >
      <mpath xlink:href="#mPath" />
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  
</svg>
```

This concept also applies to [svg motion paths.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)

**Browser support?:**
especially safari's support for `offset-path` is rather spotty [(albeit, they are apparently catching up)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Motion_Path#browser_compatibility).
Currently, svg `<mpath>` is still be a more robust option.