# Unexpected actual path when using offset-path

Tags: animation, svg, css-animations

I'm failing to understand why the observed path the shape is moving against doesn't match the path outlined by an actual circle shape drawn - despite them both having the same value for `path`: inside the `d` attributes for circle, and inside the `offset-path` attribute by the line.

What am I doing wrong?

Does this have something to do with the coordinate system? The expectation is such that the "line" `path` touches the circle and, if virtually extended, "comes out of the circle's center" (sorry, I'm not an native english speaker and not sure how to express this in proper "math/geometry english").

For context, I am trying to learn how SVG element positioning and animations work. In particular, currently I find `margin-offset: path("...")` to be quite promising when moving a shape, hoping that I can re-use the value of path for both the moving shape, and the path. However, I am apparently failing to do this even with the simplest shape possible, e.g. a `<path>` that represents a straight line.

[image]

The full HTML of my (currently failing) experiment can be see below:

```css
body {
  justify-content: center
}

.track {
  stroke: #ccc
}

.marker {
  offset-path: path('M 15 15 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0');
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0,0 25,25" width="200px" height="200px">
      <!-- the path to be animated along -->  
      <path 
           class="track"
           fill="none"
           stroke-width="0.25"
           d="M 15 15 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0"
      />
      <!-- the mover -->
      <path d="M1,1 L1,5" class="marker" stroke="red" stroke-width=0.25></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your moving/aligned element currently has the starting coordinates x:1 y:1

So these values will be added as offsets to the offset-path aligned coordinates (closely related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791786/placing-circle-along-a-straight-line-using-offset-path)).

Just change your moving path's `d` attribute to `M0 0 l0 4` or `M0 0 v4` (using vertical shorthand)

```css
body {
  justify-content: center;
}

.track {
  stroke: #ccc;
}


.marker2,
.marker {
  offset-path: path("M 15 15 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0");
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}


.marker2{
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}


@keyframes move {
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" width="200px" height="200px">

  <!-- the path to be animated along -->
  <path class="track" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" d="M 15 15 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0" />

  <!-- the mover -->
  <path d="M0 0 v4" class="marker" stroke="red" stroke-width=0.25></path>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" width="200px" height="200px">
  <!-- the path to be animated along -->
  <path class="track" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" d="M 15 15 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0" />
  <!-- the mover -->
  <path d="M0 0 v4" class="marker2" stroke="red" stroke-width=0.25></path>
</svg>
```

#### Convert path `d` attribute to use relative commands

I've changed the commands to relative commands.
This way, you can easily apply or adjust x/y offsets by changing only the M commands coordinates. Also explained in Lea Verou's article: ["Utility: Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute commands"](https://lea.verou.me/2019/05/utility-convert-svg-path-to-all-relative-or-all-absolute-commands/)

#### Some web apps to convert path data to relative commands

- [yqnn's svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)
- [thednp's svg PathCommander](https://thednp.github.io/svg-path-commander/index.html)

BTW: the `viewBox` attribute is case sensitive – always use the "camel case" notation view**B**ox.